# Resample/Upsample Period Index and using both extreme time "edges" of the data

Tags: python, parsing, pandas

I have the following DataFrame, a weekly price data timeserie with a Period Index. Let's call it `df`

```
                            timestamp         open        high        low        close  volume
timestamp                       
2009-02-01/2009-02-07   733442.166309   830.540773  832.586910  828.788627  830.706009  48401.952790
2009-02-08/2009-02-14   733449.166309   839.945279  841.763948  837.812232  839.742489  53429.330472
2009-02-15/2009-02-21   733456.245777   790.733108  792.399775  788.897523  790.549550  50671.887387
2009-02-22/2009-02-28   733463.166309   760.586910  762.640558  758.234979  760.428112  60565.506438
```

If I try to resample it with `df.resample('30min').mean()` the data ends at `2009-02-22`. I would like it to end at `2009-02-28`, while still starting at `2009-02-01`. How can I do that?
 I suspect it has to do with the `closed` and `label` values of the `resample` function, but those are not very well explained in the doc.

Here a snippet to reconstruct the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Period
dikt={'volume': {Period('2009-02-01/2009-02-07', 'W-SAT'): 48401.952789699571, Period('2009-02-08/2009-02-14', 'W-SAT'): 53429.330472103007, Period('2009-02-15/2009-02-21', 'W-SAT'): 50671.887387387389, Period('2009-02-22/2009-02-28', 'W-SAT'): 60565.506437768243}, 'close': {Period('2009-02-01/2009-02-07', 'W-SAT'): 830.70600858369096, Period('2009-02-08/2009-02-14', 'W-SAT'): 839.74248927038627, Period('2009-02-15/2009-02-21', 'W-SAT'): 790.54954954954951, Period('2009-02-22/2009-02-28', 'W-SAT'): 760.42811158798281}, 'open': {Period('2009-02-01/2009-02-07', 'W-SAT'): 830.54077253218884, Period('2009-02-08/2009-02-14', 'W-SAT'): 839.94527896995703, Period('2009-02-15/2009-02-21', 'W-SAT'): 790.73310810810813, Period('2009-02-22/2009-02-28', 'W-SAT'): 760.58690987124464}, 'high': {Period('2009-02-01/2009-02-07', 'W-SAT'): 832.58690987124464, Period('2009-02-08/2009-02-14', 'W-SAT'): 841.76394849785413, Period('2009-02-15/2009-02-21', 'W-SAT'): 792.39977477477476, Period('2009-02-22/2009-02-28', 'W-SAT'): 762.64055793991417}, 'low': {Period('2009-02-01/2009-02-07', 'W-SAT'): 828.78862660944208, Period('2009-02-08/2009-02-14', 'W-SAT'): 837.8122317596567, Period('2009-02-15/2009-02-21', 'W-SAT'): 788.89752252252254, Period('2009-02-22/2009-02-28', 'W-SAT'): 758.23497854077254}, 'timestamp': {Period('2009-02-01/2009-02-07', 'W-SAT'): 733442.16630901292, Period('2009-02-08/2009-02-14', 'W-SAT'): 733449.16630901292, Period('2009-02-15/2009-02-21', 'W-SAT'): 733456.24577702698, Period('2009-02-22/2009-02-28', 'W-SAT'): 733463.16630901292}}
pd.DataFrame(dikt, columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to include the `start_time` corresponding to the first `PeriodIndex` and `end_time` corresponding to the last one, the keyword arguments present in [`DF.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) would be of little help here as these operate as a whole/mutually exclusive in nature (meaning altering any arg would affect either the `start_time` or `end_time` but not both).

Instead, you could downsample these to take on the day frequency, `"D"` and then perform the aggregation of mean for each group within 30 minutes.

```
df.resample('D').asfreq().resample('30T').mean()
```

The `convention` arg could have been used if resampling across `start_time` or `end_time` specifically were to be performed.

---

***To check:***

```
resamp_start = df.resample('30min').mean()
resamp_all = df.resample('D').asfreq().resample('30T').mean().head(resamp_start.shape[0])
resamp_start.equals(resamp_all)
True
```

---

If you require only the resampled index and not it's aggregation, then it would make sense to down-sample it's current frequency to the lowest integer frequency corresponding to the frequency that is to be resampled for *[Here, 1 minute]* and then take slices of every 30 rows to compute this for every *30 minute* sample.

```
df.resample('T').asfreq().iloc[::30]
```

These would give you the samples for the whole of `2009-02-28` as compared to the earlier case where the dates upto and not including `2009-02-28` were considered due to their normalization (times adjusted to midnight) imposed during `.resample('D')` operation.

Comment: Yes thx it works. It is a bit confusing for me as to why using that middle step of 'D' freq changes the result?

Comment: The reason for down-sampling frequency from weekly to daily was to make sure that we have both the start and end Period dates as part of our `DateTimeIndex` for us to extrapolate our results. `asfreq()` then plays the role of modifying this and filling gaps for missing dates.

Comment: The usage of `.asfreq()` method for resampling Periods is somewhat mentioned in the docs too. Read: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#frequency-conversion-and-resampling-with-periodindex

Comment: No my question is why cannot I resample from weekly to 30min directly and get the correct result. This is quite a nasty hack... It is bad enough I have to use .mean() when I am not interested in the actual mean but just in the resampled index...