# Pandas Resample Upsample last date / edge of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, reindex

I'm trying to upsample weekly data to daily data, however, I'm having difficulty upsampling the last edge. How can I go about this?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'wk start': ['2018-08-12', '2018-08-12', '2018-08-19'], 
    'car': ['tesla model 3', 'tesla model x', 'tesla model 3'],
    'sales': [38000, 98000, 40000]})
df['wk start'] = df['wk start'].apply(
    lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
df.set_index('wk start').groupby('car').resample('D').pad()
```

This returns:

```
                             car            sales
car             wk start        
tesla model 3   2018-08-12  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-13  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-14  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-15  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-16  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-17  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-18  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-19  tesla model 3   40000

tesla model x   2018-08-12  tesla model x   98000
```

My desired output is:

```
                             car            sales
car             wk start        
tesla model 3   2018-08-12  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-13  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-14  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-15  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-16  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-17  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-18  tesla model 3   38000
                2018-08-19  tesla model 3   40000
                2018-08-20  tesla model 3   40000
                2018-08-21  tesla model 3   40000
                2018-08-22  tesla model 3   40000
                2018-08-23  tesla model 3   40000
                2018-08-24  tesla model 3   40000
                2018-08-25  tesla model 3   40000
tesla model x   2018-08-12  tesla model x   98000
                2018-08-13  tesla model x   98000
                2018-08-14  tesla model x   98000
                2018-08-15  tesla model x   98000
                2018-08-16  tesla model x   98000
                2018-08-17  tesla model x   98000
                2018-08-18  tesla model x   98000
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696355/resample-upsample-period-index-and-using-both-extreme-time-edges-of-the-data), but they're using periods and I'm looking at datetimes.

Comment: it's impossible to generate a wk start with those values given the input

Comment: @Yuca why is it impossible?

Comment: the dates are bounded by 2018-08-12 and 2018-08-19, why do you expect your output to have data with dates after 2018-08-20?

Comment: @Yuca I would think that whatever it does for 8/12, it can also do for 8/19. I think I may have to reindex instead of resample

Comment: that is not what I'm saying. Check your desired output, you have dates that are beyond the scope of your inputs. You need something to generate the future dates beyond 2018-08-19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, last edge data are excluded. Solution is add them to input `DataFrame` - my solution creates a helper `Dataframe` using [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), adds `6` days and [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)'s to original `df` before using your solution:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('wk start').drop_duplicates('car', keep='last').copy()
df1['wk start'] = df1['wk start'] + pd.Timedelta(6, unit='d')

df = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
df = df.set_index('wk start').groupby('car').resample('D').pad()
print (df)
                                    car  sales
car           wk start                        
tesla model 3 2018-08-12  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-13  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-14  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-15  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-16  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-17  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-18  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-19  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-20  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-21  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-22  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-23  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-24  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-25  tesla model 3  40000
tesla model x 2018-08-12  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-13  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-14  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-15  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-16  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-17  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-18  tesla model x  98000
```

Comment: Ah this works beautifully! Thank you! Though I must note for others that the values have to be wk values have to be sorted prior to dropping duplicates. Thanks again @jezrael

Comment: (and others) I've accepted this answer because 1) it is 0.5 sec faster than the one-liner answer and 2) it is easier to debug - thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Assign a column for the end of each of your weeks and `stack`, before using your previous `groupby` attempt:

```
(df.assign(end=df['wk start'].add(pd.DateOffset(6))).set_index(
    ['car', 'sales']).stack()
    .rename('wk start').reset_index([0, 1])
    .set_index('wk start').groupby('car')
    .resample('D').pad()
)
```

Output:

```
                                    car  sales
car           wk start
tesla model 3 2018-08-12  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-13  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-14  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-15  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-16  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-17  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-18  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-19  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-20  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-21  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-22  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-23  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-24  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-25  tesla model 3  40000
tesla model x 2018-08-12  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-13  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-14  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-15  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-16  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-17  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-18  tesla model x  98000
```

Comment: thank you for the response! This works on the data set given, but is a bit tricky to debug on my actual dataset (which has many more columns) and it is a bit slower than the accepted answer. I do appreciate the one-liner, though! @user3483203

Comment: one can even use append.. there are several options to this I believe

Answer (score 1):

you could also do:

```
(pd.melt(df.assign(w = df['wk start']+pd.DateOffset(6)),df.columns[1:],value_name =
  "wk start").drop('variable',1).set_index('wk start').groupby('car').resample('D').pad())


                                    car  sales
car           wk start                        
tesla model 3 2018-08-12  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-13  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-14  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-15  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-16  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-17  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-18  tesla model 3  38000
              2018-08-19  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-20  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-21  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-22  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-23  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-24  tesla model 3  40000
              2018-08-25  tesla model 3  40000
tesla model x 2018-08-12  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-13  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-14  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-15  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-16  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-17  tesla model x  98000
              2018-08-18  tesla model x  98000
```