# How to add rows for a timeseries dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a program that will load in a timeseries excel file into a dataframe, then I create several new columns using some basic calculations. My program is going to sometimes read in excel files that are missing months for some records. So in example below I have monthly sales data for two different stores. The stores open during different months, so their first month-end date will differ. But both should have month end data up until 9/30/2020. In my file, Store BBB has no records for 8/31/2020 and 9/30/2020 because there were no Sales during those months.

| Store | Month Opened | State | City | Month End Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 5/31/2020 | NY | New York | 5/31/2020 | 1000 |
| AAA | 5/31/2020 | NY | New York | 6/30/2020 | 5000 |
| AAA | 5/31/2020 | NY | New York | 7/30/2020 | 3000 |
| AAA | 5/31/2020 | NY | New York | 8/31/2020 | 4000 |
| AAA | 5/31/2020 | NY | New York | 9/30/2020 | 2000 |
| BBB | 6/30/2020 | CT | Hartford | 6/30/2020 | 100 |
| BBB | 6/30/2020 | CT | Hartford | 7/30/2020 | 200 |

So for any instances like this, I want to be able to add two rows for Store BBB for 8/31 and 9/30. The new rows should use the same Month Opened, State and City from the most recent month-end date. The Sales should be set to 0 for both new rows. As of right now, I do the following steps:

1. Create Dataframe "MaxDateData" with the store name and the max Month End Date for each Store and also the max Month End Date for the entire time series data frame, I name this field "Most Recent Date".

| Store | Max Month End Date | Most Recent Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 9/30/2020 | 9/30/2020 |
| BBB | 7/30/2020 | 9/30/2020 |

2. Create Dataframe "MostRecent" with the most recent row from main time series dataframe. To do this, I do an inner join between the time series dataframe and the MaxDateData on the Store Name and Max Month End Date.

| Store | Month Opened | State | City | Month End Date | Sales | Max Month End Date | Most Recent Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 5/31/2020 | NY | New York | 9/30/2020 | 2000 | 9/30/2020 | 9/30/2020 |
| BBB | 6/30/2020 | CT | Hartford | 7/30/2020 | 200 | 7/30/2020 | 9/30/2020 |

3. Create a dataframe "RequireBackfill_MostRecent" using a where clause to filter for stores where Max Month End Date < Most Recent Date. See code below. So in this example, the RequireBackfill_MostRecent table will only have a row for store BBB.

```
RequireBackfill_Stores_MostRecent = MaxDateData.where(MaxDateData['Max Month End Date'] <MaxDateData['Most Recent Date'])
RequireBackfill_MostRecent = MostRecent.merge(RequireBackfill_Stores_MostRecent,how='inner')
```

4. I then use two nested for loops to cycle through dates that I need to fill in. It leverages the RequireBackfill_MostRecent dataframe which would only contain Store BBB.

```
X=[]
end = MaxDateData['Most Recent Date'][0]
for i in MonthlyData['Month End Date'].unique():
    per1 = pd.date_range(start = i,  end = end, freq ='M') 
    for val in per1: 
        Data=[]
        Data = RequireBackfill_MostRecent[["Store"
                                           ,"Month Opened"
                                           ,"City"
                                           ,"State"
                                           ]].where(RequireBackfill_MostRecent['Max Month End date']==i).dropna()   

        Data["Month End Date"]= val                
        Data["Sales"]= 0
        X.append(Data)
NewData = pd.concat(X)
```

5. I then add in the NewData to my timeseries dataframe using concat

```
FullData_List = [MonthlyData,NewData]
FullData=pd.concat(FullData_List)
```

This whole process works but is there a much more efficient way to do this? This could become costly when I start to work with larger data.

Answer (score 0):

1. just try `upsample` of the DateTime index. ref: [pandas-resample-upsample-last-date-edge-of-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790793/pandas-resample-upsample-last-date-edge-of-data)

```
# group by `Store`
# with `Month End Date` column show be converted to DateTime

group.set_index(['Month End Date']).resample('M').asfreq()
```

2. be notice that: `7/30/2020` is not the end day of July. `7/31/2020` is. so Using this method `7/30/2020` will be a problem(convert the Month End Date as the truely end date).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the step by step approach to do this. If you have questions, let me know.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
c = ['Store','Month Opened','State','City','Month End Date','Sales']
d = [['AAA','5/31/2020','NY','New York','5/31/2020',1000],
['AAA','5/31/2020','NY','New York','6/30/2020',5000],
['AAA','5/31/2020','NY','New York','7/30/2020',3000],
['AAA','5/31/2020','NY','New York','8/31/2020',4000],
['AAA','5/31/2020','NY','New York','9/30/2020',2000],
['BBB','6/30/2020','CT','Hartford','6/30/2020',100],
['BBB','6/30/2020','CT','Hartford','7/30/2020',200],
['CCC','3/31/2020','NJ','Cranbury','3/31/2020',1500]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns = c)
df['Month Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month Opened'])
df['Month End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month End Date'])

#select last entry for each Store
df1 = df.sort_values('Month End Date').drop_duplicates('Store', keep='last').copy()

#delete all rows that have 2020-09-30. We want only ones that are less than 2020-09-30
df1 = df1[df1['Month End Date'] != '2020-09-30']

#set target end date to 2020-09-30
df1['Target_End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime ('2020-09-30')

#calculate how many rows to repeat
df1['repeats'] = df1['Target_End_Date'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - df1['Month End Date'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int)

#add 1 month to month end so we can start repeating from here
df1['Month End Date'] = df1['Month End Date'] + pd.DateOffset(months =1)

#set sales value as 0 per requirement
df1['Sales'] = 0

#repeat each row by the value in column repeats
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(df1.repeats)].reset_index(drop=True)

#reset repeats to start from 0 thru n using groupby cumcouunt
#this will be used to calculate months to increment from month end date
df1['repeats'] = df1.groupby('Store').cumcount()

#update month end date based on value in repeats
df1['Month End Date'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['Month End Date'] + pd.DateOffset(months = x['repeats']), axis=1)

#set end date to last day of the month
df1['Month End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Month End Date']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)

#drop columns that we don't need anymore. required before we concat dfs
df1.drop(columns=['Target_End_Date','repeats'],inplace=True)

#concat df and df1 to get the final dataframe
df = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)

#sort values by Store and Month End Date
df = df.sort_values(by=['Store','Month End Date'],ignore_index=True)

print (df)
```

The output of this is:

```
   Store Month Opened State      City Month End Date  Sales
0    AAA   2020-05-31    NY  New York     2020-05-31   1000
1    AAA   2020-05-31    NY  New York     2020-06-30   5000
2    AAA   2020-05-31    NY  New York     2020-07-30   3000
3    AAA   2020-05-31    NY  New York     2020-08-31   4000
4    AAA   2020-05-31    NY  New York     2020-09-30   2000
5    BBB   2020-06-30    CT  Hartford     2020-06-30    100
6    BBB   2020-06-30    CT  Hartford     2020-07-30    200
7    BBB   2020-06-30    CT  Hartford     2020-08-30      0
8    BBB   2020-06-30    CT  Hartford     2020-09-30      0
9    CCC   2020-03-31    NJ  Cranbury     2020-03-31   1500
10   CCC   2020-03-31    NJ  Cranbury     2020-04-30      0
11   CCC   2020-03-31    NJ  Cranbury     2020-05-31      0
12   CCC   2020-03-31    NJ  Cranbury     2020-06-30      0
13   CCC   2020-03-31    NJ  Cranbury     2020-07-31      0
14   CCC   2020-03-31    NJ  Cranbury     2020-08-31      0
15   CCC   2020-03-31    NJ  Cranbury     2020-09-30      0
```

Note I added one more entry with CCC to show you more variation.